# How to set a packer variable from a terraform state

Tags: terraform, packer

Working with openstack. I have a two steps process to build images with packer:
(1) create infrastructure using terraform basically, just a network routed to the internet and some security group that allows SSH
(2) build the image using packer

Problem is I need to provide the id of the network built by terraform to packer. I can do this manually by checking the state file but I was wondering what was the best practice to automate this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [terraform output](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/outputs.html) to read outputs from the state. You can pass these on as Packer variables, i.e.

```
packer build -var network=$(terraform output network_uuid) template.json
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I completely missed the mechanism of output variables and how to query for them. Thanks!

Comment: Use `terraform output --raw` to avoid spurious quotes around string variables

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion: you can call Packer from Terraform.

```
resource "null_resource" "packer_runner" {
  triggers = {
    install_script = "${sha1(file("${path.module}/scripts/app/install.sh"))}"
    packer_file    = "${sha1(file("${path.module}/packer/packer.json"))}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    working_dir = "${path.module}"
    command     = "packer build -var 'ami_name=${var.ami_name}' -var 'aws_region=${var.aws_region}' -var 'network_id=${var.network_id}' -var -parallel-builds=1 ./packer/packer.json"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

Then, on `packer.json`:

```
<...stuff...>
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": "/usr/bin/cloud-init status --wait"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "environment_vars": [
        "NETWOR_ID={{user `network_id`}}"
      ],
      "script": "./scripts/app/install.sh"
    },
<...more stuff...>
```

Comment: This would work too but would not integrate in my workflow that well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add it as a suggestion to the answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58066196/4643603) but the edit queue was full. Adding it separately then.

If you need to pass all the variables from terraform output to packer's 'input':

```
packer build $(terraform output -json | jq -j -r 'to_entries[] | " -var \(.key)=\(.value | .value)"') template.pkr.hcl
```